# kubernetes jenkins slave doesnt see master

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I'm deploying Jenkins with helm charts to GKE and having issue with jobs, mainly the slave doesn't see `tcpSlaveAgentListener` - it happens whenever i start any job - the master triggers scale of new jenkins-agent but it terminates with error like these

```
SEVERE: Failed to connect to http://jenkins.jenkins.svc.my_website:8080/tcpSlaveAgentListener/: jenkins.jenkins.svc.my_website
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to http://jenkins.jenkins.svc.my_website:8080/tcpSlaveAgentListener/: jenkins.jenkins.svc.my_website
  at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.resolve(JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.java:206)
```

I replaced my domain(like google.com) to my_website - I'm curious about the jenkins.jenkins.svc.my_domain - is it built in or do I have some duplicates somewhere? that it has so many subdomains ?

Comment: Hi, the slave connects back to Jenkins via JNLP on JNLP port (TCP port for incoming agents). If you will go to Manage > Configure Global Security; you would be able to see that; select Fixed port and specify a value say 8081. You can also use tunnel under kubernetes plugin config (Manage> configure system) and specify jenkins.jenkins.svc:8081. (if your namespace is jenkins and serive exposed name is jenkins too)

Comment: Thanks!!! that solved the issue - so configuring it under kubernetes plugin wasn't good enough apparently

Comment: Shall I add this as answer; you happy to vote and accept? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to configure TCP port for incoming agents to 50000 on master Jenkins configure section.

```
1. Go to Configure Global Security
2. Under Agents section, select Fixed option and keep 50000 value.
```

Comment: hmm that's weird I already had it set like you recommended https://imgur.com/1ErvIwl  || I also have `Enable script security for Job DSL script` enabled  and `Agent → Master Security` as well enbled

Comment: should it even resolve to my_domain ? I dont have such a long subdomain registered anywhere - shouldn't it be flexible pod ip or smth ?

Comment: hey what do you think about this config at the bottom of Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Kubernetes config ? https://imgur.com/qM5V22b I created my helm with `helm install stable/jenkins --name jenkins -f values.yaml` and in there only difference is variabel: master.componentName: jenkins-master && podName: tmp-build-worker

Comment: my bad I was going to Configure and Kubernetes plugin at the bottom - you were right from the start

Answer (score 1):

The slave connects back to Jenkins via JNLP on JNLP port (TCP port for incoming agents). If you will go to Manage > Configure Global Security; you would be able to see that; select Fixed port and specify a value say 50000.

You can also use tunnel under kubernetes plugin config (Manage> configure system) and specify jenkins.jenkins.svc:50000. (if your namespace is jenkins and serive exposed name is jenkins too)

Comment: I swapped the 8081 to 50000 as in the kubernetes plugin and then it worked